# ListView with lots of images jumps

Tags: android, listview, lazy-loading

I have a listview that contains lots of images

I have tried 3 different lazy loaders to display the images

I have disabled loading onScrollState!=IDLE

I have cancelled loading tasks when scroll began

And yet, every time i scroll - the list sort of jumps 
the log shows almost after every image, that the garbage collector is collecting something

```
09-12 16:08:20.093: D/dalvikvm(15748): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 401K, 54% free 3856K/8327K, external 12043K/12209K, paused 33ms
```

The strange part is - if i disable the image loading all together, and display no layout whatsoever

the garbage collector is still working.....

what could be causing the garbage collector to work so hard?

this is my layout

```
 <ImageView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/photo1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

this is my getView

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    ViewHolder vh;
    if(convertView == null){ 
    vh = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = (ImageView) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.photo,parent,false);
    vh.iv = convertView;
    convertView.setTag(vh);

    }else {
    vh = (ImageView) convertView.getTag();
      Log.i(TAG,"displaying old view: "+position);
    }
      lazyLoader.load(images[position],vh.iv);
    return convertView;
}

}
```

and this is the log output

[image: logouput]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Also set:

```
PauseOnScrollListener listener = new PauseOnScrollListener(
                com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance(), 
                pauseOnScroll, pauseOnFling);
list.setOnScrollListener(listener);
```

It will prevent image loading while scrolling. If the glitches still appear check your holder pattern.